# android: visual issues on a custom slider

Tags: android, slider, customization, seekbar

I created a custom slider that was working fine, but suddenly it started showing visual issues and i have no idea where to look to solve this problem.

the issue is the appearance of black borders/gradients around it. i tested on android 6 and android 4.0.3 as well. both are showing the same problem. on android 4.0.3, i can also see this problem around the actions in the toolbar when i press on them, it makes like a black gradient shadow.

[image]

any idea?

the code of my slider is:

```
public class StyledSeekBar extends SeekBar {
public StyledSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.init();
}

public StyledSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.init();
}

public StyledSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.init();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public StyledSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    this.init();
}

/**
 * Initializes the instance of this class.
 */
private void init(){
    setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apptheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_light));
    setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light));
    setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's no shadow. Looks like .png stretched. Try 9png

Comment: I suspect that you are right. I just found this webpage that is showing something similar. I will give it a try once at home. thank you! the page is there: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/working-with-9-patch-nine-patch-images-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! To fix this kind of issue, it is necessary to verify the 9-patch images and resolve all the bad patches. This can be done by using the draw9patch tool.